# How to recyle Bitmap with GridView adapter?

Tags: android, gridview, android-fragments, bitmap, android-bitmap

I have a GridView in my android app. I want to recyle all images when I click the button of BACK. I dont't know how get this?

```
gridview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This is my getView() in Adapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder = null;
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_addimage_grid,
                        parent, false);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.image = (ImageView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.item_grida_image);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            if (position == Bimp.SelectBitmap.size()) {
                holder.image.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                        getResources(), R.drawable.pic_add));
                if (position == 3) {
                    holder.image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            } else {
                holder.image.setImageBitmap(Bimp.SelectBitmap.get(position)
                        .getBitmap());
            }

            return convertView;
        }

        public class ViewHolder {
            public ImageView image;
        }
```

When I click this button, I go to another fragment:

```
case R.id.title_btn_left:           
            Bimp.SelectBitmap.clear();
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            SearchFragment searchFragment = new SearchFragment();
            ft.replace(R.id.fl_content, searchFragment);
            ft.commit();
            break;
```

Now, when I click back button, I set the *`Bimp.SelectBitmap.clear();`*. But when I get in the fragment of select images, it's too slow and don't responce the **gridview.setOnItemClickListener()**. I think because of the image is not recyle when I go to another fragment.

Comment: You want to reuse the images in your adapter when you back in your previous activity?

Comment: No, I don't need these images.

Comment: Well... if not then you can use `Bitmap.recycle()`.. loop to your list and call it before onDestroyed()

Comment: Er, I don't understand what you mean. If not in the adapter getView() function, how do I get the imageview object? Can you explain in more detail about that?

Answer (score 1):

Set `setRecyclerListener(...)` to your `GridView`:

```
gridview.setRecyclerListener(new RecyclerListener() {
    @Override
    public void onMovedToScrapHeap(View view) {
        //get Bitmap by 'view' and release it here         
    }
});
```

Hope this help!

Comment: I get another error : ' java.lang.NullPointerException'. This is my code:     Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) view.getBackground()).getBitmap();bitmap.recycle(); at onMovedToScrapHeap(View view).